# How to sum a comma separated string in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  value
1   1,2,3,4
2   2,3,4
```

So I want to get this result:

```
id   sum
1     10
2     9
```

Can I do it in SQL(MySQL)?

Comment: Why at the first place do you store your data in such an inconvenient way?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [an earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6311530/2400222). The accepted answer is to create a stored procedure (which is also provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it more dynamically Creating a function. Please follow the following steps

1. create a function that give the sum of a comma separated value

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION GetToalOfCommaSeperatedVal 
   (
     @commaSeperatedVal varchar(100)
   )
   RETURNS int
   AS
   BEGIN

       declare @sum int
       DECLARE @x XML 
       SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@commaSeperatedVal,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)

       SELECT @sum=sum(t.value('.', 'int')) 
         FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

      return @sum
   END
   GO
   ```
2. the do a just select command in the following way

   ```
   select id,dbo.GetToalOfCommaSeperatedVal(value) from YOUR_TABLE
   ```

Answer (score 3):

With great effort, you can do this.  Really, though, this is a very, very bad way to store data.

In the spirit that sometimes we have to use data whose format is not under our control:

```
select id,
       (substring_index(value, ',', 1) +
        substring_index(substring_index(concat(value, ',0'), ',', 2), ',', -1) +
        substring_index(substring_index(concat(value, ',0'), ',', 3), ',', -1) +
        substring_index(substring_index(concat(value, ',0'), ',', 4), ',', -1) +
        substring_index(substring_index(concat(value, ',0'), ',', 5), ',', -1)
       ) as thesum
from t;
```

The nested called to `substring_index()` fetch the nth value in the string.  The `concat(value, ',0')` is to handle the case where there are fewer values than expressions.  In this case, the nested `substring_index()` will return the last value for any value of n greater than the number of items in the list.  Concatenating `0` to the list ensures that this doesn't affect the sum.

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30951).