# MySql sum cell with delimited values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a legacy table with unnormalized column `evaluation` that has values like `8, 5, 9` or `7, 6`. How do I explode these string by comma and sum the value using SQL?

```
assignments table:
id | evaluation
---|------------
1  | 7,6,8
2  | 3,2

desired result:
id | score
---|------------
1  | 21
2  | 5
```

Comment: Just go through this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567706/how-to-sum-a-comma-separated-string-in-sql

Comment: Do it in your application level code i.e php for future first consider [**Database_normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I wasn't able to find that question before asking. It looks like I do have to have privilege to do stored procedures though.