# MySQL Labs JSON native type: How SUM the result of an array returned by jsn_extract?

Tags: mysql, json, nosql, mysql-5.7

Below follow my scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE `CustomerOrder` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And we can use this Customer Order json as example:

```
{ 
    "creation": "2015-07-30 14:27:51",
    "customer": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "sku": 182,
            "unitPrice": 0.89,
            "qty": 10
        }, {
            "sku": 712,
            "unitPrice": 12.99,
            "qty": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Runing on MySQL console this SQL:

`SELECT json_extract(data, '$.item[*].unitPrice') AS price  FROM CustomerOrder`;

I will have this output:

```
[ 0.89, 12.99 ]
```

Now how can I evaluate a SUM of [0.89 + 12.99] or 1..N elements of items?

For my tests I used this version of MySQL Labs:

http://downloads.mysql.com/snapshots/pb/mysql-5.7.7-labs-json/mysql-5.7.7-labs-json-linux-el6-x86_64.tar.gz

http://mysqlserverteam.com/json-labs-release-native-json-data-type-and-binary-format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't yet support table functions (hopefully soon!), so we don't have a handy JSON function to produce rows from JSON array. For now, Victor Smt's suggestion using a stored procedure would be my preference, too.

DagW

Comment: Hi Dag, thanks for yor reply - I find another solution, it's not an elegant solution but are working for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567706/how-to-sum-a-comma-separated-string-in-sql I need to convert the array (using REPLACE) as XML Schema and SUM their nodes. To be honest, it's a very ugly solution, but it's working

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use @Rick's answer but it didn't work for me. So I digged mysql documentation for mysql functions. Here's the working function for mysql 5.7.14,

```
create function sum_array_cells( input_array json )
returns double
BEGIN
    DECLARE array_length INTEGER(11);
    DECLARE retval DOUBLE(19,2);
    DECLARE cell_value DOUBLE(19,2);
    DECLARE idx INT(11);

    SELECT json_length( input_array ) INTO array_length;

    SET retval = 0.0;

    SET idx = 0;

    WHILE idx < array_length DO
        SELECT json_extract( input_array, concat( '$[', idx, ']' ) )
            INTO cell_value;

        SET retval = retval + cell_value;
        SET idx = idx + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN retval;
END
```

Then use the function as @Rick wrote:

```
select sum_array_cells( '[ 0.89, 12.99, 5.23, 2.04 ]' );
```

Comment: I can confirm this works in MariaDB 10.3.9 as well

Answer (score 5):

Use JSON_TABLE see example:

```
SET @datax = '[
  { "product":"apple",  "price": 5}, 
  { "product":"banana",  "price": 7}
]';


SELECT price.* 
FROM 
     JSON_TABLE(@datax, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                price INTEGER PATH '$.price')
     ) price;`
```

Then, add up the price.

Answer (score 2):

The following stored function does the trick for me:

```sql
delimiter $$
create function sum_array_cells( input_array json )
returns double
language sql deterministic contains sql
begin
    declare array_length integer;
    declare retval double;
    declare cell_value double;
    declare idx int;

    select json_length( input_array ) into array_length;

    set retval = 0.0;

    set idx = 0;
    while idx < array_length do
        select json_extract( input_array, concat( '$[', idx, ']' ) )
        into cell_value;

        set retval = retval + cell_value;
        set idx = idx + 1;
    end while;

    return retval;

end$$
```

Then you would invoke that function in a query like this

```
select sum_array_cells( '[ 0.89, 12.99, 5.23, 2.04 ]' );
```

Hope this helps,
-Rick

Comment: I was not able to create function with the code you gave and it didn't work even after I made it work. Heres the fixed version of your code:

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why my code example was truncated. Here's the rest of the function:

```
    select json_extract( input_array, concat( '$[', idx, ']' ) )
    into cell_value;

    set retval = retval + cell_value;
    set idx = idx + 1;
  end while;

  return retval;

end$$
```

Comment: May be a bit late, but I helped you fix the code sample.  You didn't need to wrap your code in tags.  This pieces may now be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

An optmised and updated version of [Rick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45297362/893578).
Tested on MySQL 5.7, MySQL 8.0, and MariaDB 10.3.

Note that it uses decimal for accuracy.  Feel free to change it to double or int.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION zy_json_sum ( js_array json )
RETURNS decimal(18,2) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE total decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE idx int DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT json_length( js_array ) INTO idx;
    WHILE idx > 0 DO
        SET idx = idx - 1;
        SELECT json_extract( js_array, concat( '$[', idx, ']' ) ) + total INTO total;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN total;
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT zy_json_sum( '[1.1, 2.2, "3.3 foo", null, -4.4]' )
-- Output: 2.20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT (json_extract(data, '$.item[0].unitPrice') + json_extract(data, '$.item[1].unitPrice')) AS price  FROM CustomerOrder
```

Comment: And how can I do this iteration for all elements from database?

Comment: what does it give you when you try this query?

Comment: NULL, but $.item[0].unitPrice + $.item[1].unitPrice result 13,88. But I need a iteration SUM, because each order can have N elemts. How can I SUM an customer order with 1000 itens?

Comment: just edited my answer if someone reads it later. Still thinking about your issue

Comment: you could try and write a procedure creating a temporary table for each client with the prices of items, using a for loop. Take a look here for those procedures : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql

Comment: Well, how JSON data type it's a news feature of MySQL. And his documentation will only available in MySQL Labs and mysqlserverteam.com, Another approach can be used - think, how difficult will be Math operations in array if a basic SUM needs as stored prodecure/function as helper

Comment: maybe this thought is not the best but : could you try and compute this elsewhere than in SQL?