# Sum of total comma separated values in mysql select query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have one table like below query

```
mysql> select *from DemoTable;
```

This will produce the following output −

```
+--------------------+
| ListOfValues       |
+--------------------+
| 20, 10, 40, 50, 60 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expected output is below.

```
+----------+
| TotalSum |
+----------+
|      180 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried below examples but not working any one.

```
SELECT SUM(replace(ListOfValues, ',', '')) as TotalSum FROM DemoTable;
```

Here only first value came to in output, sum is not working.

```
+----------+
| TotalSum |
+----------+
|      20 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can any one help please. I was tried so many examples taken from stackoverflow but no use.

Comment: This would be a simple SUM in SQL, if your database was designed properly (see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) for lots of other reason why your design is problematic). SUM can add up values from different rows, not all from the same field in the same row.

Comment: Since you tagged PHP, if - some a strange reason - you don't want to redesign your database, you could just get the field out of SQL into PHP, [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the variable and [sum the resulting array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: But I want to get  sum result in select query only

Comment: Well that won't be easily possible until you design your database properly. This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Study database normalisation. It would have been a good idea to learn about relational database design, _before_ trying to design a relational database!! P.S. if you don't want to use PHP, why did you tag it??

Comment: Then redesign your database to not use comma seperated lists in a column. [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462)

Comment: It looks like there are ways to do this, but they are unpleasant - see [How to sum a comma separated string in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567706/how-to-sum-a-comma-separated-string-in-sql) for example. It's really all just nasty workarounds for a nasty design. I would strongly advise fixing the root cause of the problem instead - as you'll have seen if you've read that first link I provided, if you manage to solve this particular headache, the bad design will just keep on giving you other problems instead.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments you should redesign your database to not use comma seperated lists in a column.

If that is not possible, here is a workaround using `json_table`:

```
select t.ListOfValues, sum(j.val)
from mytable t
join json_table(
  CONCAT('[', t.ListOfValues, ']'),
  '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')
) j
group by t.ListOfValues
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1bOQ1je5)

If there are duplicated `ListOfValues` then an auxiliary column can be used to provide a unique sequential number for each row :

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over( order by ListOfValues) as rn
  from mytable
)
select t.ListOfValues, sum(j.val)
from cte t
join json_table(
  CONCAT('[', t.ListOfValues, ']'),
  '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')
) j
group by t.rn, t.ListOfValues
```

check demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/gcUbdS0U

Comment: Good solution. I suggest ``trim(t.ListOfValues)``

Comment: The values are numeric, so `CONCAT('[', t.ListOfValues, ']')` is enough. https://dbfiddle.uk/Lc0pC0Pv

Comment: @ValNik trim is not needed

Comment: Just be aware that repeated `ListOfValues` will be grouped together - `(1,2,3), (1,2,3)` will result in one row with sum `12` instead of two rows with sum `6`. You either need a way to distinguish between the rows when grouping, or to use the substring_index method in the [q/a linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567706/how-to-sum-a-comma-separated-string-in-sql) by ADyson.

Comment: Good remark @user1191247 , in this case an auxiliary column can be used to provide a unique sequential number for each row https://dbfiddle.uk/gcUbdS0U

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statements.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  str varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1,7,88,56');
```

---

```
set @s=(select * FROM test);
set @t=(select replace(@s,',','+'));
set @u=concat('select ',@t);

prepare st from @u;
execute st;
```

| 1+7+88+56 |
| --- |
| 152 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cjJbnQbSRFCzg28qwPR7Mk/0)