# Calculate (sum,max,avg) comma separated column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `POIN` and has a column which have comma separated values. I want to calculate each values on the comma separated. It's looks `duplicate` question because it has answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311530/summing-a-comma-separated-column-in-mysql-4-not-5). But I want to achieved this using single query instead of create a mysql function.

This is my table looks like :

```
id    poin
------------------
1     1,5,9,3,5
2     2,4,8,5
3     4,7,9,1,5,7
```

Desired result :

```
id     max     min      sum      avg
--------------------------------------
1      1       9        23         4,6
2      8       2        19        4,75
3      9       1        33        5,5
```

Actually, I searched this in Google and this forum and didn't get a correct answer yet. I can't show what I have tried so far, because I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Can you explain why a function won't work for you?

Comment: This schema is wrong and broken. You really want a table with a column for id and column for poin, where the same id is repeated over and over, but each row only has one entry in the poin field for that id.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items in one column. It will only cause you lots of trouble. (As you've already noticed...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what application are you design, but I think it was bad design to store values in comma separated instead of create a table details. You can solved this without using a mysql function actually. First, you need to `convert comma separated columns into rows` and then you can do some calculation. This query may help you :

```
select id,max(val) as max,min(val) as min,sum(val) as sum,avg(val) as avg
from(
    select id,(substring_index(substring_index(t.poin, ',', n.n), ',', -1)) val
        from poin_dtl t cross join(
         select a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
         from 
            (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
                union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
                union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a,
            (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
                union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
                union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b
            order by n 
        ) n <-- To make this simple, Create a table with one column that has 100 rows.
    where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.poin) - length(replace(t.poin, ',', '')))
    order by val asc
) as c_rows -- c_rows = convert comma separated columns into rows
group by id
```

The results should be like this:

```
id     max     min      sum      avg
--------------------------------------
1      1       9        23        4,6
2      8       2        19        4,75
3      9       1        33        5,5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it and back again here to give some feedback.