# Select MIN/MAX column lat long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column that looks like this

[image]

How can I get the min and the max?

Here is the expected value where on the right side is the sorted one

[image]

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: my expected result here is how can i get the lowest latlong ang also the highest lat long based on value

Comment: Did you try `MIN ()`,`MAX()`

Comment: i tried that but it gives me a wrong value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746749/calculate-sum-max-avg-comma-separated-column-in-mysql This should help you.

Comment: @TechnoCrat thnx for the ref. but i think it is not based on lat and long

Comment: @NardongBagsik I just given you ref, you can make necessary changes according to your requirement.

Comment: What does max and min mean here, are we assuming this is longitude and latitude values? In your example it looks like it is only the first value that is relevant.

Comment: this is the latitude and longitude

Comment: And...? What is max and mean, max latitude or is it the coordinates that is to be sorted and if so, how?

Comment: sir based on the second pic thats how i need to sort it just only the min and max lat long

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then the accepted answer is wrong btw and you can just sort it like you sort any other column using "ORDER BY latlong"

Answer (score 1):

```
Select membername From
(Select membername,
substring_index ( membername,',',1)+substring_index ( membername,',',-1) as total
From Table1) T1
Inner Join 
(
Select Max(total) total1,Min(total) total2 From (
SELECT membername,
       substring_index ( membername,',',1)+substring_index ( membername,',',-1) as total
From Table1)T) T2
ON T1.total=T2.total1
OR T1.total=T2.total2
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f6410/1

Answer (score 1):

To sort the table according to the expected result in the question all you need is:

```
SELECT latlong 
FROM someTable
ORDER BY latlong ASC
```