# Convert a string with operation to int using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

`persons` is a tinytext field and can contain "4 + 2", "4+2", "4 +2", "5" or "" and so on.
I would like to select and `int` like 6, 6, 6, 5 and 0 from that MySQL 5.6 Table.

Tried this without success:

```
SELECT CAST(persons AS INT) FROM Table
SELECT CONVERT(INT, persons ) FROM Table
```

Comment: With 2K rep you should already know [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on SO.

Comment: so you want magic to happen? how many operations do you have in those strings? what is the list of operations? `-+/*` do you want to support braces?

Comment: No it's only + Operation or just a number or empty. It's an old database that needs to be migrated. Not looking for magic, but you never know if there is something you missed. If there is no solution will do it on server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summing a comma separated column in MySQL 4 (not 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311530/summing-a-comma-separated-column-in-mysql-4-not-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `+` is the only operator and it appears once, then:

```
select (case when col like '%+%'
             then substring_index(col, '+', 1) + substring_index(replace(col, ' ', ''), '+', -1)
             else col + 0
        end) as added_value
```

Comment: Works! I knew there must be a way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX(col  , "+", 1)+ SUBSTRING_INDEX(col  , "+", -1) as col1
   from cte where col like '%+%'
  union all
  select SUBSTRING_INDEX(col  , "+", 1) from cte where col not like '%+%'
```

output

```
  col1
    6
    6
    6
    5
```

the upper solution will work only for your sample data 
[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63981da7851dfb606b4fad4aa4aa3b96)

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work because "persons" can also be "4+2", "4 + 2" or "4+ 2" and so on. I need something like an operation interpretation.

Comment: @Mike . . . This will also return `10` instead of `5` for `'5'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i just updated answer for only sample data

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?  You may need to use something db specific.  e.g. in oracle you can do:

```
select dbms_aw.eval_number ('4+2') from dual
```

It will return 6.

Generally speaking - using dynamic SQL you can easily achieve this.

Comment: It's MySQL Version  5.6

Comment: I dont think MySQL allows dynamic SQL inside functions.  So simple route of simply letting the SQL engine do it for you will not be available.  Based on your needs if you can live with a stored procedure that can certainly call dynamic SQL.  Or you can create a function that acytually parses string on +/*- etc. and has a switch statement etc. to compute the result.  Not very complex.