# Display sum of column between two years in laravel

Tags: laravel

I  have following table i wants sum of all orders_qty in between two years & in two month. I am creating query as following which display only answer 4 and actual wants result 8(2,2,2,2)

```
orders_id  orders_qty delivery_date
1            2,2,       2019-02-01
2            2,2,       2020-02-03
```

controller:getting qty addition month wise

```
$get_month_wise_details=DB::table('orders')
    ->select('orders_qty')
    ->where('order_status',6)
    ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y-%m")'), ['2019-02','2020-02'])
    ->groupBy('orders_qty')
    ->get();

foreach ($get_month_wise_details as $month_wise_details) 
{
    $month_array=explode(',',$month_wise_details->orders_qty);
    $month_addition=array_sum($month_array);
    $sum_qty=$sum_qty+$month_addition;
}
```

controller:getting qty addition year wise

```
$get_year_wise_details=DB::table('orders')
    ->select('orders_qty')
    ->where('order_status',6)
    ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y")'), ['2019','2020'])
    ->groupBy('orders_qty')
    ->get();

foreach ($get_year_wise_details as $year_wise_details) 
{
    $year_array=explode(',',$year_wise_details->orders_qty);
    $year_addition=array_sum($year_array);
    $sum_qty=$sum_qty+$year_addition;
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311530/summing-a-comma-separated-column-in-mysql-4-not-5

Comment: You need to clarify what is in your database, what your expected output is, and what you are seeing with the code you have.