# MySQL sum latest values with multiple group by's

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with producing a MySQL query for MySQL version `5.7.29`

The data set I have looks like this (sample data):

```
| id | serial_number | reading_value | reading_date        | register_type |
|----|---------------|---------------|---------------------|---------------|
| 1  | 123           | 7492.91       | 2019-11-20 15:37:55 | import        |
| 2  | 123           | 7783.3        | 2019-11-25 11:15:47 | import        |
| 3  | 123           | 0             | 2019-11-26 13:34:01 | export        |
| 4  | 123           | 4.01          | 2019-11-27 13:52:23 | export        |
| 5  | 456           | 7404.93       | 2019-11-24 13:31:06 | import        |
| 6  | 456           | 7758.23       | 2019-11-26 13:35:02 | import        |
| 7  | 456           | 0             | 2019-11-20 15:37:55 | export        |
| 8  | 456           | 0             | 2019-11-26 13:34:01 | export        |
```

I would like to get the **sum** of the *reading_value* of the **latest** *import* and **latest** *export* for each *serial_number* to produce a data set like this:

```
| serial_number | total_value | latest_reading_date |
|---------------|-------------|---------------------|
| 123           | 7787.31     | 2019-11-27 13:52:23 | <--- id 2 and 4 from above table
| 456           | 7758.23     | 2019-11-26 13:35:02 | <--- id 6 and 8 from above table
```

- In this resulting data set, the *total_value* is the **sum** of the **latest** *import* and **latest** *export* *reading_value* of each *serial_number*
- the *latest_reading_date* is the latest (newest) **import or export** (whichever is latest) date for the *serial_number*

I have tried the following query, but it gives me the *sum* of **all** the *import* and *export* values per *serial_number* instead of just the *sum* of the **latest** *import* and **latest** *export* value of each *serial_number*.

```sql
select serial_number, sum(reading_value) as 'total_value', max(reading_date) as 'latest_reading_date'
from t1
group by serial_number
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky approach using GROUP_CONCAT function which supports sorting of aggregated values.

```sql
SELECT serial_number, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(register_type = 'import', total_value, NULL) ORDER BY reading_date DESC, id DESC), ',', 1) `latest_import`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(register_type = 'export', total_value, NULL) ORDER BY reading_date DESC, id DESC), ',', 1) `latest_export`
FROM t1
GROUP BY serial_number
```

Explanations:

- `GROUP_CONCAT(IF(register_type = 'import', total_value, NULL) ORDER BY reading_date DESC, id DESC)` - will produce a comma-separated list of `total_values` with `import` type ordered by date and id
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` - will pick up the first value from the list
- your desired value is `latest_import` + `latest_export` (+check for nulls if they're possible), I omitted that for brevity

Comment: I wrapped this in another `select` query which adds the *latest_import* and *latest_export* values together and it seems to be doing the trick for me :)

Comment: An extension to my question: How could you modify your solution to take the **three** latest *import* and **three** latest *export* values for each serial_number and add them together instead of just the latest *import* and latest *export*? I'm asking because I need to do this as well for a different data set. I want to essentially use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get first, second and third values from list. Not only the first value in the list. I hope what I am asking makes sense 

Comment: @MornéLombard well it's more complicated. There is no simple way to do that using vanilla MySQL. Option 1: get 3 latest values using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and then calculate sum of the comma-separated list using custom functions like (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6315125/2244262). Option 2: using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` pick up every value into separate column like in my solution. So you'll get 6 columns+serial_number. Option 3: in a sub-query calculate 3rd largest `ID` for every `serial_number` and then in an outer query get a sum of all values where ID >= the ID from the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions before aggregating:

```
select serial_number, sum(reading_value) as total_value, 
       max(reading_date) as latest_reading_date
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by serial_number, register_type order by reading_date) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t
group by serial_number;
```

In pre-8.0 versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select serial_number, sum(reading_value) as total_value, 
       max(reading_date) as latest_reading_date
from t1
where t1.reading_date = (select max(tt1.reading_date)
                         from t1 tt1
                         where tt1.serial_number = t1.serial_number and
                               tt1.register_type = t1.register_type
                        )
group by serial_number;
```

Comment: @Stalinko . . . Which was released about two years ago (in April 2018).

Comment: Thank you for this. Sorry I forgot to mention that my version is `5.7.29` unfortunately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and nevertheless 5.7 is still preferred version in some setups. Personally I keep using it because my large production DB starts to crash when I migrate over v8.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation with *correlated* sub-query :

```
select t1_1.serial_number, sum(t1_1.reading_value) as total_value, 
       max(t1_1.reading_date) as latest_reading_date
from t1_1
where t1_1.reading_date = (select max(t1_2.reading_date) 
                           from t1 as t1_2
                           where t1_2.serial_number = t1_1.serial_number and 
                                 t1_2.register_type = t1_1.register_type
                          )
group by t1_1.serial_number;
```